# Extracting tar file without overriding working directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a tar file that contains ***hundreds*** of spreadsheets, inside of the tar file there is a directory `home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets` what I want to do is extract a ***single file*** to a current directory, `/home/qc/me/archive` without extracting the directory inside of the tar file.

Is there a way I can do this without the entire directory getting added to the working directory?

I know that I can use `tar --extract [FILE]` but this also extracts the `home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets` directory.

Please assume I am unable to download anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the --strip-components.

`tar -xf spreadsheets.tar --strip-components 3` will extract all files of the `/home/qc/me/archive` to the current directory or if you use the -C switch, to a specified directory:

`tar -xf spreadsheets.tar --strip-components 3 -C /home/qc/me/archive`

The final line of code seems to be what you are after.

EDIT: I missed the part where you only wanted **a single file** extracted even though it was italic AND bold.
This should be more appropriate:

`tar -xf spreadsheets.tar -C /home/qc/me/archive home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/my_spreadsheet --strip-components 3`

Just tested this line and it works the way you want it.

Comment: So strip will completely wipe the directory? 
Keep in mind there will still be files inside of the tarball, and I just want to extract one or two at a time.

Comment: Edited the answer to the way you want it